# Remove/disable toolbar options from Text web part - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts

I'm working on an intranet project and one of the requirement is to be able to restrict users so that they can use only a specific font size e.g it could be Normal text but just font sizes between 10 nd 16 only.

Also not to be able to choose colors (Both font color and Highlighted color). Force them to only use black font color.

Are there any other custom text editor webpart that can be used and is it possible to remove the options above?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to remove the web part settings/options from SharePoint out of the box "Text" web part.

You can develop your own custom web part using SharePoint framework (SPFx). Check below links for more information:

1. [Overview of the SharePoint Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)
2. [Build your first SharePoint SPFx client-side web part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part)
3. [Tab Accordion Web Part with Property Field Collection Data and tinyMCE for Rich Text Editing](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-accordion-with-richtext) - refer code in this web part sample where they are using tinyMCE library for rich text editing:

   [image]

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. Do you have where I can downoad the .spkg package?

Comment: I don't think you will get readymade sppkg file for the sample. You will have to download the code and generate sppkg file on your own. Follow the steps like: https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-accordion-with-richtext#minimal-path-to-awesome

Comment: Hi @naijacoder. Can you please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.